# Pasting complex Word objects from ClipBoard

Tags: c#, ms-word, clipboard

I am trying to create a tool for fast Word math equations pasting - based on https://github.com/mjvh80/SymWin project.

I was able to do it with simple math chars, such as arrows,operations greek letters etc...

**But I've encounter this problem with a complex word objects:**

When I copy a complex object from Word - for instance a math equation. I can paste it in a word page anywhere I want. However if I paste it to a notepad and copy the pasted text and paste it back into word - word wont recognize the objects as it was copied in a first place (cause some data is lost).

I've seen that when I copy a simple matrix from word I have around 25000 Bytes (and it's in html format). When I paste in notepad and copy I have something like 92 bytes...

When I open the word file with a single matrix I can see its html encoding but I cannot paste it back (it paste as text, not as an object)..
Looks something like:

```
<m:oMathPara><m:oMath><m:d><m:dPr><m:begChr m:val="["/><m:endChr m:val="]"/><m:ctrlPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/></w:rPr></m:ctrlPr></m:dPr><m:e><m:m><m:mPr><m:mcs><m:mc><m:mcPr><m:count m:val="2"/><m:mcJc m:val="center"/></m:mcPr></m:mc></m:mcs><m:ctrlPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/></w:rPr></m:ctrlPr></m:mPr><m:mr><m:e><m:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/></w:rPr><m:t>a11</m:t></m:r></m:e><m:e><m:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/></w:rPr><m:t>a12</m:t></m:r></m:e></m:mr><m:mr><m:e><m:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/></w:rPr><m:t>a22</m:t></m:r></m:e><m:e><m:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Cambria Math" w:hAnsi="Cambria Math"/></w:rPr><m:t>a23</m:t></m:r></m:e></m:mr></m:m></m:e></m:d></m:oMath></m:oMathPara>
```

Another problem is that I cannot alter word document structure because it's opened by the Word process (I want to paste into an opened page).

I wonder if its doable…

Comment: When you copy a table from Word, it's copied into the clipboard in multiple different formats simultaneously, seven or eight of them. Not just HTML. You need to get the list of available formats from the clipboard and see which one (if any) best suits your needs. [This page should be helpful.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2thcsx4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it